# Parallel Invoke of Windows Service in c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, iis, wsdl, windows-services

I have a 3rd party SDK (Cognitec) that has a wsdl file for a windows service. I can host this wsdl file on IIS and add a Service Reference using to it from IIS. 
The service has a method called `Identify()` that takes 2 seconds. I am trying to call this method using `Parallel.For()`:

```
    Parallel.For(0, 3, i =>
    {
    var start = DateTime.Now;
    wsdl.Identify();
    var time = DateTime.Now-start;
    Console.WriteLine(time);
    }
```

The Result:
2.1204121,
4.2135541,
5.8927112

The question is why `Parallel.For()` takes different execution time every time? I tried testing the same idea in WCF service & hosted it on IIS and the time result was the same for each call.

Comment: If the service is constrained by something other than network IO, then throwing more requests at it at a faster rate won't give you a response any quicker, will it?

Comment: No, i don't think that it has any constrains. Is there any configurations that can make it accept multiple asynchronous calls?

Comment: What happens if you at the start of your program, you increase [`ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.defaultconnectionlimit.aspx) to a higher than default value, say, 20?